# Делегаты и их использование на манер событий

Tags: c#

Копаясь в книге Троэлсена по-поводу делегатов заметил такую забавную штуку что делегаты могут использоваться на манер событий и собсвтенно ввесь вопрос у меня в методе регистратора делегата который выглядит следующим образом

```
public class Car
{
    //  1.  Определить  тип  делегата.
    public delegate void CarEngineHandler(string msgForCaller);

    //  2.  Определить  переменную-член  типа  этого  делегата.
    private CarEngineHandler listOfHandlers;

    //  3.  Добавить  регистрационную  функцию  для  вызывающего  кода. 
    public void RegisterWithCarEngine(CarEngineHandler methodToCall)
    {
        listOfHandlers = methodToCall;
    }
}
```

Здесь метод RegisterWithCarEngine принимает объект делегата в в качестве параметра и затем дальше определяем метод для вызова делегата

```
//  4.  Реализовать  метод  Accelerate()  для  обращения
//  к  списку  вызовов  делегата  при  нужных  условиях.
public void Accelerate(int delta)
{
    //  Если  этот  автомобиль  сломан,  отправить  сообщение  об  этом.
    if (carIsDead)
    {
        if (listOfHandlers != null)
            listOfHandlers("Sorry,  this  car  is  dead...");
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentSpeed += delta;

        //  Автомобиль  почти  сломан?
        if (10 == (MaxSpeed - CurrentSpeed) && listOfHandlers != null)
        {
            listOfHandlers("Careful  buddy!  Gonna  blow!");
        }

        if (CurrentSpeed >= MaxSpeed)
            carIsDead = true;
        else
            Console.WriteLine("CurrentSpeed=  {0}", CurrentSpeed);
    }
}
```

И после всего этого в main'е вызываем метод для регистрации делегата,но сделано это не совсем для меня привычным образом так вроде как передаётся анонимный объект делегата(путём вызова конструктора и передаче ему имени метода) который затем присваивается тому полю что объявлено в классе для хранения информации о том что за метод будет вызван при наступлении события(здесь как бы делегатами это сделано поэтому не путайте с событиями) и вот собственно код который вызвал у меня вопрос и я хотел бы уточнить верно ли что передаётся анонимный объект делегата

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*****  Delegates  as  event  enablers  *****\n");

        //  Сначала  создать  объект  Car.
        Car cl = new Car("SlugBug", 100, 10);

        //  Теперь  сообщить  ему,  какой  метод  вызывать,
        //  когда  он  захочет  отправить  сообщение.
        cl.RegisterWithCarEngine(new Car.CarEngineHandler(OnCarEngineEvent));

        //  Ускорить  (это  инициирует  события).
        Console.WriteLine("*****  Speeding  up  *****");

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            cl.Accelerate(20);

        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }

    //  Это  цель  для  входящих  сообщений.
    public static void OnCarEngineEvent(string msg)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("\n*****  Message  From  Car  Object  *****");
        Console.WriteLine("=>  {0}", msg);
        Consоle.WriteLine("*  *  *\n");
    }
}
```

Чтобы прямо совсем конкретно то интересует строка с вызовом метода RegisterWithCarEngine и его аргумент которым по факту является вызов метода new что именно здесь произойдёт. Типа создастя объект делегата без имени и затем мы его передадим тому полю что есть в каждом объекте класса Car и таким образом запишем какой метод нужно вызывать(мне было бы понятнее если бы скажем передали переменную делегата,но здесь сделано так и я хочу уточнить верно ли понял)

Comment: отформатируйте код, читать невозможно же

Comment: момент, не во всех местах исправил не заметил

Comment: tym сам тоже понимаю что глаза режет когда те фигурные скобки как не так стоят и хотелось бы чтобы всё как в студии было расставлено,но сам не так давно здесь и не знаю как средствами этого ресурса привести в пристойный вид код из книги если знаете, то подскажите

Comment: `CarEngineHandler` - это просто сигнатура делегата, а не сам делегат. То есть ты в нём описываешь какие аргументы и какое возвращаемое значение. `new  Car.CarEngineHandler(OnCarEngineEvent))` - это уже непосредственно создание делегата, который будет вызывать метод OnCarEngineEvent при каждом вызове самого делегата. В момент вызова метода `RegisterWithCarEngine`, как и в вызове любого метода сначала просчитываются всё, что в аргументах, а уже потом это отправляется в метод. В данном случае сначала создаётся делегат, а уже готовый делегат отправляется в качестве аргумента дальше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В современных объектно-ориентированных языках принято правило *всё является объектом*. Это относится к Smalltalk, к Java и к C#.

Именно поэтому целые числа в C# это не примитивные сущности, а объекты класса `System.Int32`. То же самое и с *указателями на функции*, которые встречаются в C и C++. Для каждого такого указателя компилятор неявно генерирует класс-наследник от `System.Delegate`.

Взглянем на строку:

```
cl.RegisterWithCarEngine(new Car.CarEngineHandler(OnCarEngineEvent));
```

Здесь создаётся новый объект неявно сгенерированного класса `Car.CarEngineHandler`. Обратите внимание, что вы нигде явно этот класс не описывали, вы написали:

```
public delegate void CarEngineHandler(string msgForCaller);
```

а компилятор сгенерировал нужный класс и подходящую реализацию нескольких методов, в частности, `Invoke`.

Впрочем, в качестве *синтаксического сахара* вы можете не создавать объект явно и писать короткий код:

```
cl.RegisterWithCarEngine(OnCarEngineEvent);
```

Но в этом случае компилятор всё равно сделает то же самое, что вы писали вручную выше.

То есть да, в вашем коде будет создан объект-делегат, который будет содержать один адрес метода и этот объект будет скопирован в поле `listOfHandlers`.

Теперь о том, что из себя представляют делегаты. Исторически, когда придумывали C#, предполагали, что делегаты будут использоваться для реализации механизма событий, то есть в них можно будет хранить несколько методов-подписчиков. Виделось это так, что будут одиночные делегаты (single cast delegates), которые хранят только один адрес метода, и множественные делегаты (multi cast delegates), в которых хранятся много адресов методов.

Потом оказалось, что это всё усложняет, и делегаты в конечном счёте сделали универсальными. В .NET нет одиночных делегатов, в каждом делегате всегда может храниться много адресов методов. Тут наверное следует напомнить, что если вы используете метод класса (статический), то хранится только адрес метода, а если метод экземпляра, то хранится и адрес метода, и адрес подписанного объекта.

Теперь о том, как связаны между собой делегаты и события. Приблизительно также, как поля и свойства. К полю класса вы имеете полный доступ: можете его читать, изменять, получать его адрес. Свойства закрывают прямой доступ, и вы из всех возможностей получаете только возможность читать и писать, да и то не обязательно. Это позволяет вам не только скрывать и инкапсулировать реализацию, но ещё и позволяет применять в языке множественное наследование интерфейсов, за счёт того, что в интерфейсе нет полей, а есть только абстрактные виртуальные методы.

Точно также и событие (event) ограничивает доступ к делегату двумя операциями: добавление нового метода и удаление существующего метода, `add` и `remove`. Вы уже не можете, например, вызвать событие снаружи класса (только изнутри), и не можете очистить его полностью, хотя, если бы это было поле-делегат, вы могли бы вызывать его даже снаружи.

Ну, и как в случае со свойствами, вы можете описывать события в интерфейсах, но не можете описывать в них поля-делегаты.

Наконец, последнее, про операции `+=` и `-=`. Это тоже синтаксический сахар. Делегаты — неизменяемые объекты (immutable), поэтому вы не можете добавить к делегату ещё один метод (`+=`). Когда вы так пишите, компилятор вызывает статический метод `Delegate.Combine`, который создаёт новый делегат из старого делегата и вашего метода. Но для события `+=` означает, что компилятор вызовет неявно сгенерированный метод `add` для этого события.

Comment: Марк Шевченко(надеюсь я правильно написал вашу фамилию), меня просто  мучит вопрос что в методе где мы собственно регистрируем делигат у которго в параметрах указан объект делегата мы ему передаём не конкретный объект а через new как бы безымянный чтоли объект делегата передаём и я хотел узнать верно ли вот то что я сейчас сказад я просто видел что можно через конструктор указывать метод для делегата передавая его имя собственно вот таким образом: предположим есть у нас тип делегата Handler и идёт такое выражение 
Handler hnd1 = new Handler(Имя_метода); И здесь просто взята часть с new

Comment: @Mark, `OnCarEngine` — это не делегат, это метод. Вы не можете его передать, потому что в C# всё должно быть объектом, а адрес метода это не объект. Поэтому вам надо обернуть адрес метода в объект делегата. Да, он безымянный, но это не страшно.

Comment: Божечки мои спасибо вам это я и хотел услышать, но непонятно как ушло часа 2-3 на споры с товарищем tym который видно не имел студии или иной онлайн ide дабы проверить а сработает ли вообще просто сказал мол не работает. Вся проблема для меня была в том что мы передавали не конкретный объект а тот что создавался оператором new и выглядело оно не очень привычно для глаз

Comment: @Mark товарищ тим ни с кем не спорил, я только указал на опечатку в вашем вопросе, посетовал на плохое формирование кода и сам же вам это форматирование поправил, чтобы больше людей обратили внимание на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Товарищ tym я уже сказал что то не опечатка, а коли вы никак не уймётесь я опробую свои силы и попытаюсь парировать.
1) Делегат является ссылочным типом и поэтому когда в самом методе регистрации происходило присваивание одной переменной делегата другой она получала ссылку на объект в котором ссылки на методы что требуется вызвать
2)Таким образом мы можем передать один или несколько методов на которые ссылается передаваемый делегат
3)Ваше += как я уже говорил позволит добавлять к уже записанным методам новые,в то время как просто = будет приводить к перезаписи списку вызовов методов

Comment: А то что код не отформатирован, то да, попытался подправить и уж как вышло так вышло

Comment: Ежели моих может где-то местами не совсем понятных объяснений по-поводу = и += недостаточно возьмите книгу того Троелсена и запустите тот пример с =,а потом с += и посмотрите что произойдёт если вы с версией где просто = дважды вызовите метод регастрации  делегата естественно с различными методами,а затем проделайте всё тоже самое но с += и заметите что один вам обнуляет список вызовов а второй сохраняет что было записано раньше и добавляет ещё новый метод

Comment: @Mark 1) Когда хотите обратиться к юзеру, пишите собачку и полный ник, например @tym32167, без этого я не получу уведомление о вашем комментарии. 2) Вы меня не поняли, я указал на опечатку вот тут `listOfHandlers += rnethodToCall;` - так как переменной `rnethodToCall` в вашем коде нет, есть переменная `methodToCall`, которая отличается первой буквой в названии. Именно это я имел ввиду фразой "`(которая, кстати, неверна и не скомпилится)`". Очевидно, мне надо было яснее выражаться, согласен с тем, что по по моим комментарям это было не очевидно.

Comment: @Mark кстати, если вам ответ помог, то не забудьте поставить ему галочку, чтобы человек, что старался для вас с ответом, получил 15 очков.

Comment: @tym32167 галочку поставил, кстати подобную вешь rnethodt где rn вместо m видел у Шилдта в главе где про события и методы add и remove какая-то странная штука получается и тут и там m исковеркано в rn, совпадение, не думаю, может это пасхалка такая тот кто заметит что-то выиграл

Comment: @Mark такое бывает если читаешь пиратскую электронную книгу, которую сканировали и распознавали, автоматическое распознавание легко может перепутать m и rn

Answer (score 2):

```
listOfHandlers += rnethodToCall;

...

cl.RegisterWithCarEngine(OnCarEngineEvent);
```

Comment: это фиксит баг, но ничего не объясняет. Автору же объяснения нужны.

Comment: Порой мне кажется что я на китайском говорю или люди нарочно не читают вопрос до конца. И ещё раз повторю раз намеренно проигнорирован вопрос:
Чтобы прямо совсем конкретно то интересует строка с вызовом метода RegisterWithCarEngine и его аргумент которым по факту является вызов метода new что именно здесь произойдёт. Типа создастя объект делегата без имени и затем мы его передадим тому полю что есть в каждом объекте класса Car и таким образом запишем какой метод нужно вызывать(мне было бы понятнее если бы передали переменную делегата,но здесь сделано так и я хочу уточнить верно ли понял)

Comment: То что вы написали позволит создавать цепочку вызовов методов

Comment: @Mark скорее всего вам так ответили, потому что никто дальше этой строчки `listOfHandlers  = rnethodToCall;` (которая, кстати, неверна и не скомпилится) не читал, так как, как я уже отметил, некомфортно читать плохо форматированный код.

Comment: Видимо я слишком токсичный персонаж и мне сложно себя контролировать, но в конечном итоге пример взял с книги Троелсена и да мне известно что в книгах встречаются опечатки(сам напоролся на парочку читая Шилдта). Сейчас пойду попробую собрать этого шалтая болтая в кучу и погляжу запуститься ли,но что-то мне подсказывает что должно поскольку листая другой ресурс metanit видел там такой момент что делегаты можно складывать и делалось как-то так del = del1 + del и результатом этого действа было то что в del хранились все методы из del1 и del2

Comment: @Mark токсичность тут не при чем, надо просто учиться задавать вопросы. Чем более понятный, ясный и простой к пониманию вопрос, тем больше людей вам ответят. А если вопрос оформлен на скорую руку, если же вопрос длинный, с кучей примеров (который не нужны и которые тяжело читать), то людей, что до конца его дочитают будет гораздо меньше, а шанс понять вопрос неверно гораздо выше. Почитайте это [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: В общем всё прекрасно сработало это ниразу не баг таким образов один делегат просто получает метод/методы другого делегата, то что было написано ранее через += позволит создавать цепочку вызовов а не будет просто перезатирать лист вызовов, а теперь просто ответь на вопрос что происходит вот здесь :
cl.RegisterWithCarEngine(new  Car.CarEngineHandler(OnCarEngineEvent));